# WMTS is working with 256x256 tiles, but not with 512x512?

Tags: gdal, tiles, gdalwarp, xml, wmts

I'm working on using imagery from a web map tile service which I've cached locally as a gdal dataset. I have both 256x256 tiles and 512x512 tiles; the latter are the "retina" versions of the former; i.e. they cover the exact same area but at twice the resolution.

Here's the `wmts.xml` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<GDAL_WMTS>
    <GetCapabilitiesUrl>/path/to/my_tile_service.xml</GetCapabilitiesUrl>
  <Layer>all-activity</Layer>
  <Style>activity</Style>
  <TileMatrixSet>google3857</TileMatrixSet>
  <DataWindow>
    <UpperLeftX>-20037508.3428</UpperLeftX>
    <UpperLeftY>20037508.3428</UpperLeftY>
    <LowerRightX>20037508.34278254</LowerRightX>
    <LowerRightY>-20037508.34278254</LowerRightY>
  </DataWindow>
  <BandsCount>4</BandsCount>
  <Cache>
      <Path>../cached_tiles</Path>
      <Depth>2</Depth>
      <Extension>.png</Extension>
  </Cache>
  <UnsafeSSL>true</UnsafeSSL>
  <ZeroBlockHttpCodes>204,404</ZeroBlockHttpCodes>
  <ZeroBlockOnServerException>false</ZeroBlockOnServerException>
</GDAL_WMTS>
```

and here's the referenced `my_tile_service.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Capabilities xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/wmts/1.0" xmlns:ows="http://www.opengis.net/ows/1.1"
              xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
              xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/wmts/1.0 http://schemas.opengis.net/wmts/1.0/wmtsGetCapabilities_response.xsd"
              version="1.0.0">
    <ows:ServiceIdentification>
        <ows:Title>My Tileset</ows:Title>
        <ows:Abstract>
        </ows:Abstract>
        <ows:ServiceType>OGC WMTS</ows:ServiceType>
        <ows:ServiceTypeVersion>1.0.0</ows:ServiceTypeVersion>
        <ows:Fees>none</ows:Fees>
        <ows:AccessConstraints></ows:AccessConstraints>
    </ows:ServiceIdentification>
    <Contents>
        <Layer>
            <ows:Title>All Activity</ows:Title>
            <ows:Abstract></ows:Abstract>
            <ows:Identifier>all-activity</ows:Identifier>
            <Style isDefault="true">
                <ows:Identifier>activity</ows:Identifier>
            </Style>
            <Format>image/png</Format>
            <TileMatrixSetLink>
                <TileMatrixSet>google3857</TileMatrixSet>
            </TileMatrixSetLink>
            <ResourceURL format="image/png"
                         template="file:///path/to/my/tiles/{TileMatrix}/{TileCol}/{TileRow}.png"
                         resourceType="tile"/>
        </Layer>
        <TileMatrixSet>
            <ows:Identifier>google3857</ows:Identifier>
            <ows:BoundingBox crs="urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG:6.18.3:4326">
                <ows:LowerCorner>-180 -90</ows:LowerCorner>
                <ows:UpperCorner>180 90</ows:UpperCorner>
           </ows:BoundingBox> 
          <ows:SupportedCRS>urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG:6.18.3:3857</ows:SupportedCRS>
            <WellKnownScaleSet>urn:ogc:def:wkss:OGC:1.0:GoogleMapsCompatible</WellKnownScaleSet>
            <TileMatrix>
                <ows:Identifier>14</ows:Identifier>
                <ScaleDenominator>34123.6733416</ScaleDenominator>
                <TopLeftCorner>-20037508.3428 20037508.3428</TopLeftCorner>
                <TileWidth>256</TileWidth>
                <TileHeight>256</TileHeight>
                <MatrixWidth>16384</MatrixWidth>
                <MatrixHeight>16384</MatrixHeight>
            </TileMatrix>
        </TileMatrixSet>
    </Contents>
</Capabilities>
```

(this was adapted from a service description that had several zoom levels, I removed all but zoom level 14).

This works just fine as is, using my 256x256 tiles; e.g. the command:

```
 gdalwarp -dstnodata 255 -co COMPRESS=DEFLATE -of GTiff -r lanczos -crop_to_cutline -cutline sample_area.json wmts.xml clipped_region.tif
```

outputs a GeoTIFF file containing the pixels from my map tiles bounded by the polygon specified (in GeoJSON) in `sample_area.json`.

However, I can't seem to figure out how to make the same thing work with the 512x512 tiles. I've tried just changing the `TileWidth` and `TileHeight` values, but that appears to change the indexing, i.e. the same lat/lon is looking at different tile IDs.

What else do I need to change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per @user30184’s comment, the issue was that I needed to divide `ScaleDenominator` by 2. Then, everything worked just right.